# sqlalchemy NullPool seems not closing the underlying DBAPI connection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

If I understand the documentation correctly, session creates or checkout an existing connection from pool.
After I close the connection it goes back to connection pool but the connection to DBAPI is not closed. To close the DBAPI connection, I need to use NullPool. 
I tried to check if my understanding is correct but seems there is some disconnect.
I'm able to open a session even after creating connections using NullPool.

Below is the sample code, where it has two connections one without NullPool and one with NullPool.

```
from time import sleep
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

con_str = 'postgresql+psycopg2://pgusr:pgusr@docker-db.appnet/iamdb'

all_connections = [
    create_engine(con_str),
    create_engine(con_str, poolclass=NullPool),
]


def get_qry(ssn_rows):
    return f'SELECT * FROM users LIMIT {ssn_rows}'


def get_ssn(cnx):
    SessionClass = sessionmaker(bind=cnx)
    return SessionClass()

def test_ssn(ssn, records):
    print('')
    print(list(ssn.execute(get_qry(records))))


for cnx in all_connections:
    ssn = get_ssn(cnx)
    test_ssn(ssn, 3)
    ssn.close()
    sleep(1.5)
    ssn = get_ssn(cnx)
    test_ssn(ssn, 5)
```

Above code executed successfully, where I expected, in the second iteration(where NullPool connection is chosen) it should throws an error while trying to create a session for the second time i.e. after the first session is closed because in case of NullPool the connection to DBAPI should also have closed. However in contrast, both the connections were able to open multiple sessions.

**Am I missing something here?**
**How do I close the connection to DBAPI after the session is closed?**

Comment: NullPool *creates a new connection each time* you checkout, and closes the created connection on checkin. It'd be rather useless if it did not.

Comment: Yeah, I'm unable to understand what was happening. Were you able to check the code, am I missing something in the code?

Comment: I do not understand what it is that might be missing. Both of the two sessions get their own connections that are then closed when either explicitly requested, or when the session goes out of scope and it is garbage collected.